# В Google Chrome не работает Yandex Api 2.1

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yandex-maps-api

Всем доброго времени суток!
Перестала работать карта на Yandex Api 2.1 в Google Chrome. Работала неделю и вдруг просто перестала((
Выдает ошибку Error: ymaps.modules: redefinition of route-content__icon.
В Firefox и Опере все работает.

Comment: Ссылка на сайт? Пример кода? Хоть что-нибудь?

Comment: Какую версию подключаете? Воспроизводится только в хром? Проверьте сейчас, пожалуйста)

Comment: версия апи, Yandex Api 2.1, версия хрома, последняя, не работает только в хроме на винде), сайт https://vsaunah.ru/

Comment: Аналогино. С картой ничего не делал Яндекс что-то намудрил, скорее всего. То есть в данном случае сижу и жду, когда яндекс устранит проблему

Comment: у вас прямо сейчас не работает? У меня всё ок, если не работает, дайте, плиз, ссылку на сайт

Comment: https://spb.allcafe.ru/catalog/map/

Comment: а почему думаете, что проблема в API? все ошибки в консоли про другое

Comment: Не работает в гугл хроме: http://joxi.ru/E2pvWbbf9Kp4gr

Comment: у меня сейчас на этом сайте в вин7 в хроме открывается карта, попробуйте кеш почистить, что-то странное

Comment: попробуйте кеш почистить

Comment: Да, заработало. Проблема была на стороне яндекса? Пользователям нужно кэш чистить?

Comment: скорее всего нет, там была кратковременная проблема, просто вы ровно попали в нужный момент и закешировали "бяку" - потому и был эффект, что проблема только в хроме

Comment: Ок, спасибо за оперативность